# Duplicate column error when using @Any in hibernate 6

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to upgrade from hibernate 5 to version 6. One feature i have been using till now is the @Any annotation, which i am trying to get working on v6. Here's my basic example schema(on h2 db)

```
create table property_holder
(
    id            bigint not null,
    property_type varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
);

create table string_property
(
    id      bigint not null,
    "name"  varchar(255),
    "value" varchar(255),
    primary key (id)
);


create table integer_property
(
    id      bigint not null,
    "name"  varchar(255),
    "value" integer,
    primary key (id)
);
```

Here's my hibernate model:

```
public interface Property<T> {
    Long getId();

    String getName();

    T getValue();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "integer_property")
public class IntegerProperty implements Property<Integer> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private Integer value;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "string_property")
public class StringProperty implements Property<String> {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "property_holder")
public class PropertyHolder {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "property_type")
    private String propertyType;

    @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "property_type"))
    @AnyMetaDef(metaType = "string", idType = "long", metaValues = {
            @MetaValue(value = "S", targetEntity = StringProperty.class),
            @MetaValue(value = "I", targetEntity = IntegerProperty.class)
    })
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Property property;
}
```

As you can see, i've used the 'id' column in the property_holder for both primary key as well as the join column for the @Any annotated 'property' field in PropertyHolder. This works great on hibernate 5

Hibernate 6 deprecated @AnyMetaDef and this should be changed to:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "property_holder")
public class PropertyHolder {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "property_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String propertyType;

    @Any
    @AnyKeyJavaClass(Long.class)
    @AnyDiscriminator(DiscriminatorType.STRING)
    @AnyDiscriminatorValues({
            @AnyDiscriminatorValue(discriminator = "I", entity = IntegerProperty.class),
            @AnyDiscriminatorValue(discriminator = "S", entity = StringProperty.class)
    })
    @Column(name = "property_type")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Property property;
}
```

When i do this, hibernate throws the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Column 'id' is duplicated in mapping for entity 'com.example.anytest.model.PropertyHolder' (use '@Column(insertable=false, updatable=false)' when mapping multiple properties to the same column)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:1054)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:1080)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:1110)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:754)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:509)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:251)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1455)
```

I tried setting updatable=false, insertable=false to the @JoinColumn declaration as

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
```

but to no avail. The only thing that worked for me is setting the @JoinColumn name to something else like:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id2")
```

If i let hibernate create ddl for me, it creates an extra column for the @Joincolumn like:

```
create table property_holder (id bigint not null, id2 bigint, property_type varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

But this is not a solution for me. I can't simply add another column to the property_holder table.

This is a huge breaking change with no solution as of yet(for me). I want to know if anyone has found a solution to this

Here is a github project demonstrating the issue: https://github.com/kausha1n/hibernate-any-issue

Branch `hibernate5-example` shows my current setup, branch `hibernate6-example` show how its not working in hibernate6

Comment: Your `PropertyHolder` entity, did it really have 2 `id` columns?

Comment: It has only one id column. However, i want to also use it as joincolumn for the @Any mapping(which works in hibernate5)